# How can I call another site?

Tags: php

How can I open another site from PHP in the Background? 
I try to use the bit.ly API.

Comment: Another site? Hiperlink?!

Please be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to guess what you want here. If you want to make an HTTP GET request from a PHP script, use the functions [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) or [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

CURL can help you. It opens a request and saves the result of next site to a variable .